# Showing a geometrical equality based on trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Let ABC be an isoceles triangle(AB=AC),draw an altitude from the vertice B that intersects with the line (AC) in point B'. Let M be a point on the line segment [BC],H is the orthogonal projection of M on the line (AB) and K is the orthogonal projection og M on the line (AC). Show that BB'=MK+MH based on the trigonometric relations cos, sin and tan.
My approach: I draw another altitude from the vertice A to make 4 right angle triangles appear, then I applied the cos rule on some angles of these triangles, until I got this equality: $$\frac{CH}{AC}= \frac{B'C}{2CH}$$ but I don't seem to make any progress.
P.S here is the shape:
https://www.geogebra.org/m/xdupx5ng

Comment: Your posting would really benefit from a diagram.  For help managing an image, see the Images section, at the bottom of 
[this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and see also 
[this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/recommendation-enhance-the-mathse-html-markdown-help-article-re-images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I do not believe there is any need for trigonometry but of simple observations from Euclidean Geometry

Project from M, an altitude to $\overline{BB'}$, which we will call $\overline{MI}$

$\overline{MI}$ is parallel to $\overline{AC}$ (The two lines are perpendicular to $\overline{BB'}$ )
Thus,
$\angle{BMI} = \angle{BCA}$ (The angles are corresponding. (1)

$\angle{MBH} = \angle{CBA} = \angle{BCA}$ (2)

(This is because $\angle{CBA}$ is just an extension of $\angle{MBH}$ and $\angle{CBA}$ and $\angle{BCA}$ are base angles of an isosceles triangle.)

Since $\angle{BMI}$ = $\angle{MBH}$ by (1) and (2),
$\angle{BHM}$ = $\angle{BIM}$ = $90°$ and the two triangles share $\overline{BM}$, then by ASA, the triangles, $\Delta{BHM}$ and $\Delta{MIB}$ are congruent. (Note that this works only because the side they share is corresponding)

Then, $\overline{HM} = \overline{BI}$ (3)

Also, $\overline{MK} = \overline{IB'}$
because MIB'K is a rectangle.
(4)

Since $\overline{BI} + \overline{IB'} = \overline{BB'}$
Then, by (3) and (4), $\overline{HM} + \overline{MK} = \overline{BB'}$

Comment: Thanks you so much, very clever solution